# Nivo slider conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I'm using a jquery plug-in scrolling plug-in called smint which is working fine, but as soon as I add in a nivo slider plug-in, smint stops working. I've followed the steps i've read in order to resolve this issue but I can't seem to find a fix. Can anyone kindly help?

Here's the header code;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.smint.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery('.subMenu').smint({
            'scrollSpeed' : 1000
        });
    });

    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What's your console is saying?

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict();` removes `$` global reference to jQuery, your posted code looks wrong

Comment: add <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
 at the start

Comment: When you use noConflict() for jQuery, you should stop casting jQuery from "$" sign, you shoud use jQuery(document) instead $(document) for exaple.

Comment: I've changed the code (edited above) but still no fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As yoou use noConflict() ,instead of $ sign use , jQuery. You need to include   jQuery.noConflict(); once ,not twice.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
jQuery('.subMenu').smint({
    'scrollSpeed' : 1000
});
});

jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
```

Comment: see console errors are there on your site                    Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined jquery.smint.js:6
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: HAHA check <head> tag ,You commented jquery path ::) and you hope to work  :)

Comment: <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->  I CAN CLEARLY SEE commented